# Basic division for token math

Tags: token, transfer, math

Here's a common scenario: Suppose an associated token account has 100 tokens of a token whose Decimal is 8. If we scale up the balance wrt the decimals of the token, the balance is `100 * 10^8`, or plainly: `10000000000`.

Now lets assume this account interacts with some smart contract such that it needs to make 5 token transfers of equal amounts. This is easy since the division is neat and clean. `100/5 = 20`. Therefore, you would transfer `2000000000` of the token account balance in each transfer instruction.

Now lets assume this account once again holds it's original balance and now needs to make 9 transfers of equal amounts. The division is no longer so simple: `100/9 = 11.1111111111` and decimals are now involved in the scaled up version of the token balance.

How should this situation be handled (9 equal transfers that total up to 100 tokens with 8 decimal places)? Should we simply ignore the decimals portion in the scaled up token balance number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solana tokens are not infinitely divisible.
The smallest amount of token is defined by the `decimals` option.
You simply can't divide the token any further.

So if you have `10*100,000,000` tokens and you want to divide it equally among three people, it simply isn't possible.

You'll have to send the three people `333,333,333` tokens each and give the remaining `1` to someone else.